# Streaming Xbox 360 screen to Windows

Tags: windows-7, video-streaming, xbox360

I was wondering if there is any way to stream my Xbox screen to my computer (Windows 7). I'm currently trying to develop a simple Xbox game, and I'd like to see what I compiled picture in picture in Windows. Is there any way to accomplish this, preferably over my network?

Answer (score 2):

as with any video signal you can send it over the network once properly encoded and served. Connecting a [slingbox](http://www.slingbox.com/go/slingbox#.UHX8pfmfH38) is probably the most straightforward way of doing it. At $299 for HDMI it's not the cheapest thing to do.

Also Microsoft is supposed to be launching [smartglass](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/smartglass) but this is probably going to work more like airplay were you can send video from computer / device to xbox not the other way around.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, But you will need a PC running windows 10. Next go to the Xbox app in your PC.
Pair your PC to your Xbox 360, Then, Done!

Comment: No; what you describe does not work for Xbox 360